# How can I distinguish mysql master binlog dump threads when there are 2 mysql slave instance on same server?

Tags: mysql, replication

There are 2 mysql slave instance setup on a server, and one master instance setup on another server.

When "show processlist;" on master, there are 2 different binlog dump threads.

How can I distinguish between one binlog dump threads from the other (which slave use which thread)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made [a mysql plugin](https://github.com/ikarishinjieva/mysql_plugin-binlog_dump_list) for it.

Demo:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.binlog_dump_list;
+----+----------------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | HOST           | PORT | USER | STATUS                                                                |
+----+----------------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 192.168.56.202 | 3306 | repl | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated |
|  3 | 192.168.56.202 | 3406 | repl | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated |
+----+----------------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```